# Python - Load AIML file from a directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, aiml

I'am trying to run an aiml file with python. `myfile.py` and `myaiml.aiml` in one directory. When I double-click `myfile.py` in my directory inside python directory, aiml file is loaded, but when I run it from cmd with command: `python directory\myfile.py`, aiml file is not loaded. What's the difference?

My code :

```
import aiml

k = aiml.Kernel()

k.learn("myaiml.aiml")

while True:
    input = raw_input("> ")
    response = k.respond(input)
    print response
```

When I try to change the code to `k.learn("C:Python27\directory\myaiml.aiml")`, it can't load too.

I've try to move the those to python directory, and run it with command : `python myfile.py` and it works. But how if I want to make those files in other directory and run it from cmd. Could it be?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the real path:

```
import aiml
import os

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

k = aiml.Kernel()

k.learn(path + "/myaiml.aiml")

while True:
    input = raw_input("> ")
    response = k.respond(input)
    print response
```

Hope it helps.